# reconstruct amount of time with excel

Tags: excel

I have a reporting tool that formats the amount of time data as hh:mm / h:mm. When the csv is generated and opened with excel some of the data is misrepresented.

For example `39:52` (39 mins, 52 secs) becomes `39:52:00` (39 hours...) but the strange thing is this doesn't happen to all the data, it seems to only do it when the data exceeds `23:00`.

I would like a formula to be able to reconstruct the values as follows:

- If the cell value contains a single column `:` e.g. `10:16` then
  prepend with `00:` so it ends up as `00:10:16`
- If the cell value contains two columns `:` e.g. `39:52:00` then
  reconstruct a new value by dropping the trailing `:00` and prepending with `00:`
  so it ends up with `00:39:52`

Comment: A text sample of the relevant CSV that is causing the problem would be useful in not only figuring out what is going on, but also in suggesting a robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

What appeared to fix it cleanly is `=A1/60` where A1 contains the duration value 39:52:00

The result is 0:39:52